# Get String of a TypeScript String Enum

Tags: typescript, enums

The string of an enum can be obtained as below:

```
enum eURL {
    projects
    }

let x:string = eURL[eURL.projects]; //x= 'projects'
```

However, if I use string enums as in the example below, then how can I get the string value "Help Me" from the enum?

```
enum myEnum {
    projects = "Help Me",
}

let x:string = myEnum[myEnum.projects]; // returns undefined.
```

Answer (score 3):

You just use it directly:

```
let x:string = myEnum.projects;
```

[Live copy on the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20myEnum%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20projects%20%3D%20%22Help%20Me%22%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20y%3A%20string%20%3D%20myEnum.projects%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(%60y%20%3D%20%24%7By%7D%60)%3B).

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the obvious eludes

Answer (score 0):

The reason why first example works and second not is connected to how is typescript transpiling normal enum vs string enum.
Normal:

```
(function (myEnum) {
    myEnum[myEnum["projects"] = 0] = "projects";
})(myEnum || (myEnum = {}));
```

It uses index as key and also value as key and do mapping from value to index and index to value and produce object which look like this:

```
{0: "projects", projects: 0}
```

String:

```
(function (myEnum) {
    myEnum["projects"] = "Help Me";
})(myEnum || (myEnum = {}));
```

String enum on the other hand map only key to value and produce this:

```
{projects: 0}
```